# Why would you use a scope when you could use regular Ruby class methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Scopes

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :most_recent, -> (limit) { order("created_at desc").limit(limit) }
end
```

using scope

```
@recent_comments = Comment.most_recent(5)
```

Class Methods

In Model

```
def self.most_recent(limit)
  order("created_at desc").limit(limit)
end
```

In controller

```
@recent_comments = Comment.most_recent(5)
```

Why would you use a scope when you could use regular Ruby class methods?

Comment: clean explanation of the difference is here: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest reason to use `scopes` is because it would always return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, even if the scope evaluates to `nil` unlike the class method. You can also add specific methods to a scope which are not going to be present in the class unless the scope is called.

```
scope :lovely, -> name { where(name: name) if name.present? }
```

this would return the collection if there is no name. But in class method, you would have to do something like this

```
def self.lovely(name)
  if name.present?
   where(name: name)
  else
   all
  end
end
```

You can find more documentation of scopes here: [Active Record scopes vs class methods](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/) and here: [Should You Use Scopes or Class Methods?](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/should-you-use-scopes-or-class-methods/) and [ActiveRecord::Scoping::Named::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html)